# What does _ngcontent-c# mean in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm learning Angular 2/4 and I see the html tags with the ng generated attributes: `_ngcontent-c0, _ngcontent-c1...`

What does this c value mean?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

`_ngcontent-c#` attributes are added when you use `ViewEncapsulation.Emulated` - which is default. Angular uses these attributes to target specific elements with the styles. The number `c` is sort of a unique identifier of the host component. For example, if you have two components with the following templates:

```
ComponentA
<span></span>
<comp-b></comp-b>

ComponenB
<h1></h1>
```

Angular will mark all elements with styles inside component `A` as `_ngcontent-c0` and all elements with styles inside component `B` with `_ngcontent-c1`:

```
<comp-a>
    <span _ngcontent-c0></span>
    <comp-b _ngcontent-c0>
        <h1 _ngcontent-c1></h1>
    </comp-b>
</comp-a>
```

Comment: So the root component will be 0 and nested ones would go 1...n?

Comment: Not sure I like or want / need this `_ngcontent..`   how do i turn it off ?

Comment: @TomStickel, what [view encapsulation](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewEncapsulation) are you using? If you use Native or None, Angular shouldn't add these attributes

Comment: Well I came from Angular 1 world ,  dabbled with angular 2 -   then got into 4, and now new project from scratch with angular 5.    I have been using Angular CLI,  I have not intentionally added any view encapsulation so this is all new to me.   I don't recall the _ngcontent on last contract project with angular 4, so I'm unsure about this  "Native" vs "None"  -  Is angular CLI adding it when I'm using ng serve ?

Comment: @TomStickel, ViewEncapsulation.Emulated is default mode. It's specified in the Component decorator descriptor properties

Comment: All good and well, but what effect do the _ngcontent-c# have?

Comment: @Scott, can you clarify what you mean? I used `#` instead of a number. It's used to target CSS selectors and apply encapsulated styles

Comment: @AngularInDepth.com right, but I mean what specific styles are applied using it?

Comment: @Scott, they depend on what styles you used in your `style` property of Angular decorator

Comment: You can follow this link. 
    https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2015/06/29/shadow-dom-strategies-in-angular2.html

Comment: "when you use ViewEncapsulation.Emulated"?  This is confusing.  I didn't use ViewEncapsulation.Emulated!  Can you re-write that so it's clearer?  "By default, Angular... This is technically ViewEncapsulation.Emulated"

Comment: @MaxKoretskyi, would you be able to help with an issue I'm having?  I'm trying to create a reusable form in Angular to use on other pages.  I'm not getting any errors but the component is not showing up.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72788182/cant-see-content-of-reusable-angular-form-on-home-page

Answer (score 17):

you can disable it by adding below import to your component,

```
import {ViewEncapsulation} from '@angular/core';

import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-dashboard',
  templateUrl: './dashboard.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dashboard.component.css'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

please note this line :

```
 encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
```

make no addition of dynamic attribute from angular