# Can't see content of reusable angular form on home page

Tags: html, angular, ionic-framework, angular-forms

I'm trying to create a reusable Angular form in an Ionic app.  After following several tutorials and Stack posts I no longer have any errors but the content isn't showing on the parent page.

My reusable component:

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-profile-form',
  templateUrl: './profile-form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./profile-form.component.scss'],
})
export class ProfileFormComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {}

}
```

```html
<p>
  profile-form works! BLAH!!!!!
</p>
```

After reading a stack post I manually created a module for the component because Ionic doesn't generate modules when you create a component via the CLI.

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { IonicModule } from '@ionic/angular';


import { ProfileFormComponent } from './profile-form.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    IonicModule,
  ],
  exports: [ProfileFormComponent],
  declarations: [ProfileFormComponent]
})
export class ProfileFormModule {}
```

Then I added it to the module of the parent page:

```js
import { ProfileFormComponent } from 'src/app/forms/profile-form/profile-form.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    IonicModule,
    ProfilePageRoutingModule
  ],
  declarations: [ProfilePage, ProfileFormComponent]
})
```

```html
  <div>
    <app-profile-form></app-profile-form>
  </div>
```

I'm not getting any errors but I'm unable to see the content of the reusable component on the parent page.

Angular CLI: 14.0.2
Node: 16.13.2
Package Manager: npm 8.1.2
OS: darwin x64

Angular: 14.0.3
... common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... language-service, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic
... router

### Package                         Version

@angular-devkit/architect       0.1400.2
@angular-devkit/build-angular   14.0.2
@angular-devkit/core            14.0.2
@angular-devkit/schematics      14.0.2
@angular/fire                   7.4.1
@schematics/angular             14.0.2
rxjs                            6.6.7
typescript                      4.7.4
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

What's weird is if I inspect the page I can see the element:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Open `app-profile-form` more in the html inspector, what's the contents? Anyway `ProfileFormComponent` should be in declarations of `@NgModule` no need to export it. Remove `ProfileFormModule` entirely and add `ProfileFormComponent` to declarations of `AppModule`

Comment: I added the screen shot

Comment: Did you try what I suggested? Remove `ProfileFormModule` entirely and add `ProfileFormComponent` to declarations of `AppModule` and you should be good to go.

Comment: I did try that.  In the app module:

  declarations: [AppComponent, ProfileFormComponent], still getting this error:

core.mjs:10540 NG0304: 'app-profile-form' is not a known element (used in the 'ProfilePage' component template):
1. If 'app-profile-form' is an Angular component, then verify that it is a part of an @NgModule where this component is declared.
2. If 'app-profile-form' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.

Comment: I know it's weird, but the only way for me to get rid of that error is to create a module for the component and then actually import the module into the parent component where I want to use it.  The error goes away in the console but the content won't show up in the page.  When I use your suggestion I only get the error.  Keep in mind I'm auto generating the component in the Ionic CLI so I'm not sure what may be missing.

Comment: For completeness sake - also reload everything (restart ng serve).

Comment: I have been.  This is just weird, no errors now and I can inspect the element and see the html from the child component but it's not appearing on the page.

Comment: Also go over some CSS styles, maybe something else is hiding it now that've gotten rid of the errors.

Comment: It was the stupid .css.  Thanks for your help Joosep

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to create a module for **ProfileFormComponent** you just need to declare ProfileFormComponent in a specific module for example in app.module.ts

But if you want to use this component or any reusable component in other modules you should put it on the shared module or create your own module and import it to the specific module you want

Comment: when I declare ProfileFormComponent  in app.module.ts i get the following error:

core.mjs:10540 NG0304: 'app-profile-form' is not a known element (used in the 'ProfilePage' component template):
1. If 'app-profile-form' is an Angular component, then verify that it is a part of an @NgModule where this component is declared.
2. If 'app-profile-form' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.

Comment: Here's the declaration in app.module.ts

  declarations: [AppComponent, ProfileFormComponent],